# Current required to keep an iron bar in a solenoid

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electromagnetism, magnetic-fields, electric-current

I found myself reading some lecture notes on magnetism and tried out the challenge question: http://spiff.rit.edu/classes/phys313/lectures/sol/sol_f01_long.html (At the bottom of the page).

What I did was first calculate the volume of the bar, then the mass and then the force required to hold it against gravity, assuming g = 10.

For this I got that the force required was: ~0.02N

Using this value I tried to calculate the required magnetic field B and got: 2 * $\sqrt{μ_0 / \pi}$

I then tried calculating the current required and got: 1 /100 * $\sqrt{1 / ( μ_0 * \pi )}$

Calculating this I get ~5A.

I found the answer and dont know what I did wrong: http://spiff.rit.edu/classes/phys313/quiz/quiz.24.html

Should I have used E$_h$ = mgh somewhere?

Comment: I think that bar weighs much more than $0.02N$.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to Michael Richmond.

He setup the question from the link above and responded to my email query with the following:

$$n = N/l = 200/0.2 = 1000 turns / m$$

$$µ_{m} = 2\times10^{-2} T/A^2$$
$$µ_{0} = 1.26\times10^{-6}N/A^2$$
$$ρ = 7800 kg/m^3$$

Mass of the bar:
$$m = ρ \pi r^2l = 7800(\pi(0.02m)^2(0.2m)) = 1.96kg$$

Force of gravity:
$$F_{g} = mg = 19.2N$$

Magnetic force (From an energy perspective):
$$F_{B} = \frac{\pi r^2B^2}{2µ_{0}}(µ_{m}/µ_{0} -1) = \frac{\pi r^2(µ_{0}nI)^2}{2µ_{0}}(µ_{m}/µ_{0} -1) = \frac{\pi (0.02m)^2(µ_{0}1000I)^2}{2µ_{0}}(µ_{m}/µ_{0} -1) = 7.9\times10^{-4} (15.872) I^2 = 12.6I^2$$

Therefore the current is:
$$F_{B} = F_{g} \to I^2 = \frac{F_{B}}{12.6} \to I = 1.2A$$

Looking at this I made two mistakes;

1. I tried working in cubic meters and then switched to meters, getting a force of 0.02N
2. I accidentally simplified $$(µ_{m}/µ_{0} - 1) = 1$$

Comment: It looks like you have $n=1000$ but the problem says $n=200$.  Am I misunderstanding this?  And it looks like you changed $19.2N$ to $12.6$.

Answer (score 0):

I believe there is a error in the solution you posted and also in the link in your question. I believe the error to be in viewgraph 11 where the author correctly states that if one "fills the space with some substance, one must use the magnetic permeability of that substance". However the author proceeds to write $$U=V\frac{B^2}{2\mu_0}\frac{\mu_m}{\mu_0}$$ when instead it should be $$U=V\frac{B^2}{2\mu_m}$$ to emphasize why I believe this is a error I refer to "Physics Handbook for Science and Engineering Ninth edition page 235" where the energy density formula is $$U=V\frac{B^2}{2\mu_r\mu_0}$$

With this error in mind the calculation then turns out to be:
$I=\sqrt{\frac{2F}{k\pi}}\frac{L}{r\mu_0N}$ where $k=\frac{1}{\mu_0}-\frac{1}{\mu_m}$
with $F\approx20N$, $L=0.2m$, $k\approx795724 \,T/A^2$ ,$N=200$, $\mu_0=4\pi*10^{-7}$, $r=0.02m$

$$I\approx160A$$